# Not able to connect SQL Server using Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sql-server-2017

I am running my python code over Ubuntu which connects to Remote SQL Server 2012. Server Details as below:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

While connecting I am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connection.py", line 12, in connectSqlServer
    connection =pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+SQLSERVERHOST+';DATABASE='+SQLSERVERDB+';UID='+SQLSERVERUSER+';PWD='+ SQLSERVERPWD)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I am able to Telnet the IP over port 1433. Requested to help me out. I am using pyodbc. Other way around for connectionstring will work too.

Comment: Have a look at the SQL Server's log, and get the true authentication failure reason.

Comment: Using sqlcmd with right or wrong any credentials, It Says:
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.

Comment: Does your password, per chance, have a `$` in it?

Comment: yes it's there.

Comment: But even with other user name or password it's giving same error. It's on very first instance. Seems some version / configuration issue of ubuntu

Comment: I have no problems connecting from Ubuntu to SQL Server. In fact, Ubuntu is a supported operating system.

Comment: Which ODBC driver you are using and what is the server configuration along with your Opes SSL version?

Comment: I'm, unfortunately, at the office today, @Kartikeya, so not something i can confirm at the moment.